# How do I localize ag-grid default datepicker?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, internationalization, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

is there any way to use translations on default ag-grid datepicker?
In this example i want to translate the word `December`

[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x07RZ.png)

Was expecting that passing -

```
 localeText={{
          December: 'Whatever',
          ...
        }}
```

would be enough but its not working...